# Analyzing values of rasters with different resolution

Tags: qgis, raster

I have two rasters, on precipitation and population, and the precipitation raster is at a larger resolution.

I am interested in creating a table which tells me all of the values of the smaller resolution population rasters for each larger resolution precipitation raster. For instance:

[image]

I know how to do this with ArcGIS (using Tabulate Intersect), but I do not have access to ArcGIS at the moment.

I am looking to conduct this analysis for 15 countries for about 240 months.

Here is a visual example for Austria:

- Here, the precipitation data is at larger resolution in the purples and blues, for one month (Jan 1991)
- The population data is in the smaller resolution in the greens

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS Processing Toolbox, go to `SAGA | Vector <-> raster`.

[image]

(1) Run `Raster values to points` tool to extract values from your finer grid cells (your population) to a new point layer.

(2) Then using this point layer and the coarse grid (your precipitation) raster layer, run `Add raster values to points`.